# series $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

I have the following series: $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots$$ I want to know whether this series converges or not.

**My Attempt**

$$\frac{\text{nth term}}{(n-1)\text{th term}}=\frac{n-1}{n}=1-\frac{1}{n}$$

As $$n\rightarrow \infty,  \frac{\text{nth term}}{(n-1)\text{th term}}=1$$

But as  we know that the series does not converge, so what is wrong with my argument?

Comment: No conclusion can be made for the ratio test when the limit tends to 1

Comment: At the moment you haven't stated an argument - perhaps you should make an accurate statement of the ratio test, and see what, if anything, you can conclude from that.

Comment: @MarkBennet, thank you mark, I get your response :)

Comment: @John, thank you John :)

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33441/why-is-the-ratio-test-for-l-1-inconclusive

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the series 1 + 1 + 1 + .... The ratio of two consecutive terms is 1, but the series obviously diverges. This should help you remember that the ratio test is inconclusive when the ratio is 1, at least if you can remember another example (e.g., 1 + 1/4 + 1/9 + 1/25 + ...) which has ratio 1 but converges.