# If $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \nearrow 1$ when $n \to \infty$, does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $(a_{n})$ is a sequence which satisfies $a_{n} > 0, \forall n \in  \mathbb{N}$.

The ratio test states that if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \to L < 1$ when $n \to \infty$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges. This can be proved showing that for large $n$, the sequence will be bounded by a geometric sequence whose sum converges. See more info in the question bellow:

[Why is the ratio test for $L=1$ inconclusive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33441/why-is-the-ratio-test-for-l-1-inconclusive)

However, if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} < 1$ for all natural $n$ and $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = 1$$
Will the series converge?

Comment: Try the most simple example of a divergent series you can think of...

Comment: Did you even read the page you are linking to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, and even the counterexample remains the same as for the ratio test with $L=1$:

$$a_n = \frac1n$$
means that $$\frac{\frac1{n+1}}{\frac1n} = \frac n{n+1} < 1$$
and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1} = 1$$

but the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$$(as you should know) does not converge.

Comment: On the other hand, for $b_n=1/n^2$, we have $b_{n+1}/b_n\uparrow 1$ and the series $\sum_{n\ge1}b_n$ converges.

Comment: Ow, this was obvious... however, I believe that  $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \searrow 1$ when $n \to \infty$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ diverges... I'm not sure if it actually holds, but I think such a sequence will not converge to 0 (hence the series won't converge). The case I asked in this question is, however, inconclusive.

Comment: the "however , I believe" is true almost straighforward, as then for almost all indexes $\;n\;$ , the sequence $\;\{a_n\}\;$ is monotonically ascending and positive...

Comment: @Timbuc "Allmost"? You mean all, right?

Comment: @5xum I can't tell that. For example, the sequence $\;\{-1,0,-1,0,-1,2,\frac32,\frac43,\frac54,\ldots,\}\;$ is mon. descending to $\;1\;$  for *almost* all $\;n\;$ ...or the sequence $\;\{\sqrt[n]n\}\;$ is monot. descending to $\;1\;$ for $\;n\ge 3\;$ , say.

Answer (score 4):

No. Consider the harmonic series.